# About Python MatchObject

Tags: python

I'm learning Python regular expressions and I have a question: all books and Python documents I have read tell me that `re.search` returns a `MatchObject` or `None`.

My question is where is the definition of `MatchObject`? What class does `MatchObject` belongs to? When I use `help(matchObj)`, it prints `<'_sre.SRE_Match'>`. What is this?

Comment: [docs for MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/match-objects.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a type defined in C, specifically in [`_sre.{so,pyd,dylib}`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Modules/_sre.c#l3612).

Answer (score 2):

[This is a definition from official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects)